# How to use multiple build.gradle files?

Tags: build, intellij-idea, gradle, project, structure

My project structure is:

[image]

I want user additionally to configure the build using some of the build scripts from **specifications** dir but the main build script to be used to configure the project as well. Using **-b** *option*  give the ability to specify another build scrpt different from the default one, but I want this default one to be executed as well. I don't want to use **apply from:** and to add all scripts because user have to decide what he wants.

So is there a way to tell Gradle to add additional build script - command line with which to configure extra the **Project**?

Comment: Why does the user have to decide what he wants? Please give a concrete use case.

Comment: For example in oop.gradle user wants to use java plugin and specify sourceCompatibility 1.8, use specific quality check plugins, add additional tasks, extra properties, specify from where the sources can be taken. But in example.gradle user wants sourceCompatibility 1.4,  add tasks ,etc. . In other build script apply C, in another C++ plugin. I know that some of this configurations can be pass as arguments but want to help user just to write something like -Pspec=example like Oli Charlesworth said and not to configure anything else.

Comment: Why should the user have to pass this every time he runs the build?

Comment: He should not. And for that reason this configurations are in the build script files but must not be apply at the same time, because if we suppose that oop and exaple do the same thing but the place from where take sources, the values of the extra properties, output directories are different using the right scritp will facilitate user work to write only 10 letters.

Comment: I don't understand. In your question you say "is there a way to tell Gradle to add additional build script - command line", yet the script shouldn't be specified on the command line? Why doesn't the user add a simple `apply from:` then?

Comment: Because it is not allow users to change directly the build scripts. They can only execute what they want. They can pass on the Jenkins extra properties, system properties etc. but not changing the scripts. And it is not suppose that users understand Gradle. You say them if you want to build 1.8 compatible java project and want sources to be taken from www.example/com/sources and uploaded to www.... execute build with gradlew ....... and do not touch thinks that do not understand. If want to change something we will create another script and you will use it and will have no problems.

Comment: I don't believe in this philosophy. And how do users run local builds then, without having to pass complicated command line arguments every time? Anyway, if these are your requirements, just go with something similar to Oli's suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need this this, you could do something like this:

```
apply from: "config/specifications/${project.spec}.gradle"
```

which would then allow users to do e.g.

```
./gradlew -P spec=example
```

See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties for more details on setting project properties from the command line.